# Is this normal behavior? single-spa activeWhen

Tags: single-spa, single-spa-angular

activeWhen is listening to url

and we have A B C apps and our url structure has to be hostname/A/B/C
If I want to display only C microApp, activeWhen("hostname/A/B/C")
but all the parent apps from A and B will also appear..
Is anyway to workaround (not changing url structure).
And Why it would load all parent apps.  isn't activeWhen need to be matched not partially matched?

Another question, how to force load app just like single-spa-inspector

Thank you for looking into it

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a work around.

When you pass a sting to the activeWhen array it will match when the URL starts with that string. So your parent apps which have `activeWhen: ['/a']` and `activeWhen: ['/a/b']` will also match hostname/A/B/C. This is helpful with nested routing.

If you want to match only when the pathname equals a string exactly you can add a function to the activeWhen array instead of a string. Functions in the activeWhen array will receive `window.location` as an argument.

Example:

```js
singleSpa.registerApplication({
  name: 'a',
  app: () => import('src/a.js'),
  activeWhen: [(location) => location.pathname === '/a'] // will only match '/a' exactly
});

singleSpa.registerApplication({
  name: 'b',
  app: () => import('src/b.js'),
  activeWhen: [(location) => location.pathname === '/b'] // will only match '/b' exactly
});

singleSpa.registerApplication({
  name: 'c',
  app: () => import('src/c.js'),
  activeWhen: [(location) => location.pathname === '/a/b/c'] // will only match '/a/b/c' exactly
});
```